# Puppet agent cannot find environment

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

Puppet master can find the environment,

```
[user@puppetmaster]$ sudo puppet agent --configprint modulepath
/etc/puppet/environments/development/modules:/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

but the agent cannot:

```
[user@puppetagent]$ sudo puppet agent --configprint modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

puppet.conf

```
[main]
environmentpath = $confdir/environments

[agent]
environment=development
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both pieces of output from different hosts?  They both say "user@host".

If the second is from another server, which is a client of the Puppet master, then this seems entirely fine.  The agent doesn't know or care about the modulepath, it's part of the master configuration only, which compiles the manifests into a catalog for the agent.

If you're experiencing a problem that's led you to look at this setting, perhaps re-post with details of that issue.

Comment: Pieces are from different hosts. As a workaround a `basemodulepath` has been overwritten in the puppet.conf that resides on the agents. The expectation was that changing it on the master would be sufficient for agents to find the right environment.